# Add badge in GridView for unread notification Android

Tags: android, mysql, gridview, notifications

Hello I have my custom `GridViewAdapter` where I have 7 voice.

```
String[] description = new String[]{"test", "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "notification"};
int[] imageId = {
                R.mipmap.test,
                R.mipmap.test1,
                R.mipmap.test2,
                R.mipmap.test3,
                R.mipmap.test4,
                R.mipmap.test5,
                R.mipmap.notification,
        };
```

And in my DB (mySQL db) I have a table for notification where I know if one notification is read or not.
So i would like put a badge in Element notification with number of notification unread.

The actual layout of grid element is:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="88dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    />
```

And I believe that if I add a TextView in rowLayout  (Like below) could be work

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/unread"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
```

But with this method I will see `TextView` in all element.
How can I put this textView only for one element and refresh number when the notification will add?

I see this post https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger
and https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger
but seems deprecated.

My `Adapter` is:

```
    public class GridViewDashboardAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public class Holder
    {
        TextView tv;
        TextView notification;
        ImageView img;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)    {
        Holder holder = new Holder();
        View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_grid, null);
        holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        holder.notification=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        holder.img=(de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
        holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
         /* pseudo code */
        if(notificationUnread.size()>0){
            holder.notification.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you didn't show the code where you change the visibility of TextView to visible.

Comment: hello, thankyou, I add snippet of adapter

Comment: what is `notificationUnread`?

Comment: as for now = you 100% need to add else {} to your if, and set textview to gone there

Comment: btw, @VasilyKabunov is right, this might be a problem

Comment: Thankyou all :) , but I'm new in android dev. :) so only way for see a badge in one element is put a textView and show or not if one condition is satisfied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace

```
android:visible="gone"
```

to

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

In the `getView` you can change visibility like this:

```
if (notificationUnread.size()>0){
    holder.notification.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    holder.notification.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: hello thanks, sorry it is a my copy error I will edit.
My problem is , show badge only one element in GridView

Comment: I see your edit, but so only way for see a badge in one element is put a textView and show or not if one condition is satisfied?

Comment: I updated the answer. Try to hide the element if it's should not be visible. Also what is `notificationUnread` variable?

Comment: notificationUnread is array of notification unread that I get from my db with volleyRequest

Comment: Right. You have to add textview to the layout and show/hide it for each record. `notificationUnread` variable should be different for each row. So if it an array, you have to check the concrete element of this array (related to the concrete element of your list)